# how I can use push notification in my application?

Tags: java, android, notifications, push

I want to use push notification in my application. but I don't know where in which activity I must add it. I have around 7 activities.

I try and add to different activity but It doesn't work.Is there any one to help me or suggest me a way how to use?

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(this, "", "");


    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

// If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

    }




public class ParseStarterProjectActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // To track statistics around application
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

    // inform the Parse Cloud that it is ready for notifications
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, ParseStarterProjectActivity.class);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse.initialize(this, "", ""); enter your both key in that field

define application class in application

define all permission required

import parse .jar into your project

Comment: what is your error.. show your all error msg and also show your manifest file

Comment: I don't have any errors ... I don't know where I ADD these codes. in which activity? DO I make individual activity for push?